# regular expression search and replace in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, search, replace

How can we achieve this in a single sql (mysql) query ?

I need to search some patterns in a column and if any pattern matches then replace that pattern with a specific string.
like if

```
   pattern ptr1 matches then replace this with str1
   pattern ptr2 matches then replace this with str2
```

I need a function like replace that can replace a regular expression.
here is my query i need to improve this for regular expression

```
UPDATE category SET column1 = 
(
    CASE
    WHEN (column1 REGEXP 'xy') THEN REPLACE(column1, 'xy' , 'ffff')
    ELSE column1
    END
)
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: Thanks I tried that function but did not work. its working this way when i am passing a string like UPDATE category SET column1 = 
(CASE
WHEN (column1 REGEXP '^xy') THEN regex_replace ('^xy' , 'ffff','kunal pawar')
ELSE column1
END)   but did not work when i pass column name  like -  UPDATE category SET column1 = 
(CASE
WHEN (column1 REGEXP '^xy') THEN regex_replace ('^xy' , 'ffff',column1)
ELSE column1
END)

Comment: If you solved the problem, go ahead and answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

you can put multiple replace function while updating table values -

```
UPDATE category SET column1 = 
REPLACE(REPLACE(column1, 
                ptr1, 
                str1),
        ptr2,
        str2)
```

Comment: actually my problem is like that - suppose i have a column `name` and then if i get kunal# in name then kunal# should be replaced by pawar and if i find kunal@ in the name then it should be replaced by pawar-1

for ex


hidfds kunal# 434fdwef    -> hidfds pawar 434fdwef

hidfds kunal@ 434fdwef    -> hidfds pawar-1 434fdwef